# jQuery datatables columnDefs target a name rather than index

Tags: jquery, datatables

In this code:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": 0,
      "searchable": false
    } ]
} );
```

targets has been given a column index. But in my case, columns can be in varying orders. So my question is, can "targets" be given the name of the column parameter and if so, how?

Comment: You are using a JSON datasource? How does your columns looks like?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) (emphasis mine):

> This `targets` property tells DataTables which column(s) the
>   definition should be applied to. It can be:
>
> - 0 or a positive integer - column index counting from the left
> - A negative integer - column index counting from the right
> - **A string - class name will be matched on the TH for the column**
> - The string "_all" - all columns (i.e. assign a default)

Comment: targets with class name doesn't work, detail here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26357/unable-to-get-columndefs-render-to-work-on-columns-coming-from-ajax-request

Comment: seems to be fixed. i just used it. header in html, ie `<th class='col-name'>` and then using it in the options: `columnDefs: [ { targets: "col-name", visible: false }]`.